# How do I access images locally in Android?

Tags: android

so I am currently making an Android assistant application (Similar to Siri, Google voice, etc). I need to retrieve images when the assistant is invoked (when home button is held). How do I do this without making calls to libraries or anything that will take a lot of server time? I want to be able to do this locally. I know the Assist Structure has Window and View Nodes that can get the content text and descriptions, but I dont know how to get images.

Thanks!

Comment: i dont get what you want to achive

Comment: Can you give us a bit more detail on what you're trying to do and where the images would show? If you want an image to show inside an assistant card you'd need to configure the url on your server, which should add it to the card's response.

Comment: Welcome to SO Ali . To ask a question you need to elaborate what exactly you want to achieve and what have you done so far . Provide some Code snippet You or a flow chart of problem . Then it will easy for anyone to get the problem .

Comment: @Fabio I am creating an assistant, such as siri, and I need to retrieve images from the current webpage that I am on when the assistant is invoked (long press on home button)

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I want to create an Assistant using Android Assistant API. I need to retrieve all of the images on whatever page is on screen when the assistant is invoked and store them in a data structure of some sort.